toolkit:MediaElement does not play local files
I want to create simple audio player using MAUI in Visual Studio 2022.
But when I use toolkit:MediaElement it plays remote file very well but when i want to play file in local that is in my phone it does not play the file. Both the embed:// and filesystem:// don't work.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">

            <toolkit:MediaElement
                   x:Name="mediaElement"
                   ShouldAutoPlay="True"
                   ShouldShowPlaybackControls="True"
                   Source="filesystem://2.mp3"
                   HeightRequest="300"
                   WidthRequest="400" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>


where is the file located?  Is it part of your project at build time, or something that you download later?  If its included at build time, what is the build action set to?

Is there any log on this problem which can help us locate the problem?

no , there is no log on this problem and when I put the file in the resources folder and I use embed://2.mp3 it works fine but i want to access all the mp3 file in my android phone  . I cheeked all needed permissions in androidmainfest.xml file like read-media-audio and read-external-storage

Can you tell me exactly where your mp3 files are stored on your Android device? And could you please post more code snippets so that we can test on our side?

My files are in /storage/emuted/0/Music and when i use filesystem or mediaelement.fromfile("/storage/emuted/0/Music") nothing happens i tested /data/user/0/com.mycompany/files/Music/myfile.mp3 for address in code and in xml  either and nothing happens

I found a problem with the spelling of your path.  It should be /storage/emulated not /storage/emuted.

And you can debug your code step by step, which can help you find the specific cause of the problem.

Yes , but there is no problem and just nothing happens when i want to access to storage files by filesystem or mediaelement.fromfile() function

Could you please post a basic demo here so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?
